# Fix 404 error after changing permalink structure

Tags: permalinks, 404-error

hope you are all doing good!

I have this problem. I had set "Post Name" as the URL scheme, therefore, I get www.site.com/article-title for blog entries. I've written a few test posts and I realize I want permalinks to look like this:

For blog posts: www.site.com/blog/article-title. For categories: www.site.come/blog/category/category-name. For tags: www.site.com/blog/tag/tag-name

So I made the following changes in the permalink settings page:

[image: Custom Permalink Settings]

And now I get the error 404 when I access a post or a page. What can I do in order to fix the problem? Thanks in advance! :D

PD. Sorry if my English sounds odd, Spanish is my native language.

Comment: Do the new posts you add work? Have you tried saving the permalinks again? You can go to settings > permalinks and hit save. This might fix it

Comment: @Fraggy Yeah, I had tried that. It was a .htaccess file issue . This link helped me to fix the problem: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Fixing_.htaccess_Generation_Issues

Comment: I solved this issue by [this way](https://www.mallutechie.com/blog/2020/04/25/how-to-fix-the-permalink-404-error-on-wordpress/)

Answer (score 1):

If your .htaccess file were writable, wordpress do this automatically, but it isn’t so these are the mod_rewrite rules you should have in your .htaccess file.

1- Open .htaccess file and copy following data in that file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

2.After update file permalink issue will resolve.